# For which rational $q$ is $\cos q\pi$ of the form $r+s\surd n$, where $r$ and $s$ are rational and $n$ is an integer?

Tags: trigonometry, algebraic-number-theory

It's well known that $\cos q\pi$ is of the form $r+s\surd n$, where $r$ and $s$ are rational and $n$ is an integer, when $q$ is a multiple of $\frac14$, $\frac15$, or $\frac16$. Are there other such examples with rational $q$?

Comment: You already exhausted all possibilities. $\mathbb{Q}(\cos (2\pi/n))$ is the maximal real subfield of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$, so former has degree $\phi(n)/2$, it is $\leq 2$ iff $n=1,2,3,4,5,6,8,10$ or $12$.

Comment: @pisco : No-one has answered so far. Would you consider posting your comment as an answer so that we can upvote it and accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments:

You have already exhausted all possibilities. The field $\mathbb{Q}(\cos(2\pi/n))$ is the maximal real subfield of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$, and so the former has degree $\varphi(n)/2$, which is $\leqslant 2$ iff $n=1,2,3,4,5,6,8,10$, or $12$.